# How does Salesforce behave during scheduled outages?

Tags: api, webservices

If you have a scheduled outage with Salesforce in which Salesforce is 'Completely unavailable' what error message does a client of the APIs see when someone tries to call it?

Is it a login failure?  A 500 server error?

Comment: I'd imagine that any attempt to login would result in an error similar to if you're trying to login in the front end and, for example, the pod your org is hosted on is 'having a lie down'. How this manifests itself as a server response though - no idea. It would be great to have all the error codes explained in documentation so that connecting systems know what to expect and configured accordingly.

Comment: Its a critical component to building recoverable services, its key to understand the difference between a expected and unexpected failure.   I see some testing in my future.

Comment: I get "Could not connect to host" error in my log when there is outage or there is performance degradation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scheduled outages, it is *usually* a 503/Server Unavailable

However, those can also happen for unscheduled outages (that, or a 500/Internal Server Error)

We've run both apps against the SOAP API for years, and some more recent apps against the REST API (Apex REST). I don't recall ever seeing a different error code.

Additionally, you should code for timeout errors like Atul suggested since when Salesforce is having a bad day ("performance degradation"), the requests will probably never return at all.

Comment: Rats! Our instance went through Spring'14 last weekend, and I had this question bookmarked to come back with an answer, but I got sick, and completely forgot to test.

Comment: The major upgrades (Spring/Summer/Winter) are supposedly "5 minute upgrades" -- at least, that's how they're advertised so it's hard to measure those outages. It's the other random ones that they have on the weekends that are longer and tend to raise 503/Server Unavailables